# Why fancy indexing is not same as slicing in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have been learning *Fancy indexing* but when I observed the behavior of the following code I got a couple of questions...

According to my understanding,
**Fancy Indexing** is: 
 
`ndArray[ [0,1,2] ]` i.e. passing a list of rows / columns

and

**Slicing** is: 
`ndArray[ 0:3 ]` i.e. giving a range of rows / columns

---

### **Now, the problem**

A numpy array,

```
arr = [ [1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9] ]
```

When I try fancy indexing:

```
arr[ [0,1], [1,2] ]
>>> [2, 6]
```

And when slice it,

```
arr[:2, 1:]
>>> [ [2, 3],
      [5, 6] ]
```

Essentially both of them should return the two-dimension array as both of them mean the same, as they are used interchangeably!

```
:2 should be equivalent to [0,1]           #For rows
1: should be equivalent to [1,2]           #For cols
```

---

> The question:
> Why Fancy indexing is not returning as the slice notation? And how to achieve that?

---

Please enlighten me.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand why you expect same results. `arr[ [0,1], [1,2] ]` returns a list with two elements: first element from row 0 col 1 and second element from row 1 and col 2. `arr[:2, 1:]` returns a two dimensional sub array with rows 0 - 1 and cols 1 - 2. That's expected and documented behavior: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: @ThomasSablik but when I do arr[ [0,1] ] ~ pass only list of rows means the same as arr[:2] so when combined with columns it should return the same!

Comment: `2 ** 2` and `2 * 2` and `2 + 2` return the same result. Does it mean for you that the operators `**`, `*` and `+` have always to do the same? You found a special case where fancy indexing and slicing return the same result but usually they behave differently. One of the most important rules in programming is: don't expect anything. Read the documentation.

Comment: When indexing one dimension, 1:4 and [1,2,3] select the same thing.  But in 2d, a pair of lists is not the same as slices.  Read the full numpy indexing documentation.

Comment: @ThomasSablik, I am satisfied with your explanation but the thing is when we 'slice' we are constrained accessing the rows or columns sequentially. I mean arr[:3,2:] will follow the sequence 0,1,2 rows and 2,3 columns and can't assess from between. To access in manual order we do something called 'Fancy indexing'. But as its behavior we are not getting whole set of rows instead we get the value where they both intersect. What if I want to access row = [0,2,1] and col = [1,0,2] manner and want whole rows and columns? I appreciate your way to answer.

Comment: Did you read the integer array indexing section?  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#purely-integer-array-indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancy indexing and slicing behave differently **by definition** / by **`numpy` specification**.

So, instead of questioning why that is so, it is better to:

- Be able to recognize / distinguish / tell them apart (i.e., have a clear understanding of when does the indexing become fancy indexing, and when is it slicing).
- Be aware of the differences in their semantics (outcomes).

In your example:

In the case of fancy indexing, the indices generated for the two axes are combined "in tandem" (similar to how the `zip` function combines two input sequences "in tandem". (In the words of the official `numpy` documentation, the two index arrays are "iterated together"). We are passing the list `[0, 1]` for indexing the array on axis `0`, and passing the list `[1, 2]` for indexing the array on axis `1`. The index `0` from the index array `[0, 1]` is combined **only** with the **corresponding** index `1` of the index array `[1, 2]`. Similarly, the index `1` of the index array `[0, 1]` is combined **only** with the **corresponding** index `2` of the index array `[1, 2]`. In other words, the index arrays **do not** combine with each other in a many-to-many fashion. All this was about fancy indexing.

In the case of slicing, the slice `:2` that is specified for axis `0` conceptually generates indices '0' and '1' for axis `0`; and the slice `1:` specified for axis `1` conceptually generates indices `1` and `2` for axis `1`. But these generated indices combine in a **many-to-many** fashion, unlike in the case of fancy indexing. So, they produce **four** combinations rather than just two.

So, the crucial difference in the defined semantics of fancy indexing and slicing is that in the case of fancy indexing, the fancy index arrays are **iterated together**.